# python tkinter button set variable to false

Tags: python, tkinter

I don't really know to set a variable by pressing a button in python. For example:

```
done = False
...
range_button = Button(self.parent, text="start", command=lambda....
...
while done:
     .....
```

But i don't really know how to do something like this in python, any help?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special about doing this with Tkinter -- if done is a global variable (or an instance variable) just set it to whatever value you want. The important part is, it must be a non-local variable.

```
range_button = Button(..., command=stop_loop)

def stop_root():
    global done
    done = True

def something_else():
    global done
    while !done:
        ...
```

Strictly speaking, you don't need the `global done` statement in the function with the loop, since that function isn't changing the value of the variable. However, I think it makes the intent of your code a little more evident.